# Unable to use ssm client.put_parameter() providing the Tier parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssm

When I try to use SSM client.put_parameter() providing the Tier parameter, I get the following error:

> Parameter validation failed:
>
> An unknown parameter in input: "Tier", must be one of Name, Description, Value, Type, KeyId, Overwrite, AllowedPattern

```
boto3 version: 1.7.74
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2034


    print("boto3 version: "+boto3.__version__)
            Policies = {}
            Policies['Type'] = "Expiration"
            Policies['Version'] = "1.0"
            Attributes = {}
            Attributes['Timestamp'] = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=24)
            Policies['Attributes'] = Attributes
            ssm.put_parameter(
                Name="**************",
                Description='string',
                Value="*************",
                Type='String',
                Overwrite=True,
                Tier='Advanced'
            )
```

Expecting to put parameter with Tier and policy

Answer (score 3):

As per the `put_parameter` [1.7.74 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.7.74/reference/services/ssm.html?highlight=put_parameter#SSM.Client.put_parameter), it doesn't support `Tier` argument. I'm assuming you're referring to the latest (1.9.212) documentation.

This is a known issue with lambda. Boto3 release changes effect lambda execution environment only after new lambda release, means even if there's a new boto3 version lambda wouldn't be having the latest module. Alternatively you can create a lambda layer with your latest boto3 module and configure your lambda function to use the same.

[AWS Lambda Layers - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path)

Comment: Some people have pre-built such layers, eg: [keithrozario/Klayers: AWS Lambda Layers for Python](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I would still suggest to build and own the layers. This is an easy way, but there are risks.